# Ajax not returning anything on form submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am working in wordpress and on pressing the submit button I want the function to return result through ajax and result should be shown as an alert on the screen. But when I press submit nothing shows.

Below is my code

Ajax code (ajaxinsert.js file)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    jQuery("#addimage").submit(function (e) { //form is intercepted
        e.preventDefault();
        //serialize the form which contains secretcode
        var sentdataa = $(this).serializeArray();

        //Add the additional param to the data        
        sentdataa.push({
            name: 'action',
            value: 'wp_up'
        })

        //set sentdata as the data to be sent
        jQuery.post(yess.ajaxurl, sentdataa, function (rez) { //start of funciton
            alert(rez);

            return false;
        } //end of function
        ,
        'html'); //set the dataType as json, so you will get the parsed data in the callback
    }); // submit end here
});
```

HTML Form

```
<form id="addimage" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="submit" name="upload" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
</form>
```

PHP code (I have used shortcode on the page for this code and below code is in functions.php file)
add_shortcode( 'test', 'addimage' );

```
function wp_up()
{   
echo "zeeshanaslamdurrani";
exit();

}

function addimage(){  

add_action( 'wp_ajax_wp_up', 'wp_up' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wp_up', 'wp_up');


// register & enqueue a javascript file called globals.js
wp_register_script( 'globalss', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/js/ajaxinsert.js", array( 'jquery' ) ); 
wp_enqueue_script( 'globalss' );

// use wp_localize_script to pass PHP variables into javascript
wp_localize_script( 'globalss', 'yess', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
```

Comment: If you open your network pane in inspect element and submit the form, do you get any message and/or error?

Comment: there are no errors in console and I am using a theme called Dynamix ... do you think something else is conflicting with the ajax code ... on document ready if you show alert it shows the alert but the value returned from function through ajax that does not show.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try after putting the below mentioned hooks outside the `add_image()`function :

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wp_up', 'wp_up' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wp_up', 'wp_up');
```

Comment: no thanks Jenis ... still the page half refreshes like it seems as if ajax is working but the alert(rez) does not show it should show when I press the submit button.

Comment: Please make sure you are getting value in `yess.ajaxurl` .

Comment: how can i check that ... any suggestion please

Comment: try to `alert(yess.ajaxurl)` before `jquery.post`

Comment: no alert message is shown ... nothing is returned this means

Comment: so what should I do it's not returning anything